# How do I make this guitar sound?

Tags: studio, guitar

I'm a new musician trying to become comfortable with FL Studio 11. Most of my difficulties lie in creating the sounds that I hear in my head. With that in mind, how should I go about making or finding a guitar sound similar to the one at 1:05 in this song without a live recording?

Comment: So you're trying to create guitar sounds but don't want to play guitar, have I got that right? _Why_?

Comment: I don't have a guitar, and even if I did, I doubt I could process it into something similar without knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: "without knowing what I'm doing". So you mean, you want something but you don't want to invest in it? That's probably not the best way to get it IMHO. Furthermore, this is rather off topic.

Comment: No, I asked the question because I wanted to know how to go about producing the sound, hence knowing what I'm doing; so yes, I am willing to invest in it.

Comment: @ArnoudTraa: Where does it say this question is off topic for this StackExchange?

Comment: @Shannon: Two things: 
1. Where do you read music producers in the following text? "Sound Design Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts. It's 100% free, no registration required. " 
2. We're working on getting a new text, excluding music production, check out meta.stackexchange. Your welcome to join the discussion on this.

Comment: @BubbleMonkey: Sorry, you're not making a lot of sense here. You want to create a guitar-sound without a guitar and you only want to know how to 'produce' the sound? Then what would be your input?

Comment: @ArnoudTraa: Where is that text you quote? I can't see it on the "what topics can I ask about here" help page. I asked about this on meta and the only responder was for including music production questions. http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/q/248/9422

Comment: it's confusing i know... if you log out (or use another browser) you see it on the landing page..

Answer (score 2):

Fender Stratocaster (or other twangy sounding guitar, anything with a single coil pick up should do), through a compressor, DI into your DAW, then apply light digital delay in post production. You will need to find some one to play the part though.

Answer (score 1):

This track sounds like he was playing an Omnisphere guitar patch and bending the pitch wheel.  It doesn't really sound like a real guitar performance to me.

b

Answer (score 0):

Buy a guitar or find yourself a guitar player to team up with. A sampler might get you into similar territory if you have the right samples but it will still just be an approximation and might not sound convincing as a guitar.